# Create the following parametric plot of circles with Mathematica (image)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, calculus

[The only thing that is given is that the red circle has a radius of 2 and intersects the center of the black circles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmhxws.png)

[image]

Comment: you need to explain better what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @agentp Sorry this is my first time on here. I'm having trouble figuring out the equations for the circles, not including the red one which I already knew

Comment: I guess this is homework, are you required to use `ParametricPlot`? I would just use graphics circles, then you just need to know the centers and radii, which i hope you can work out easily by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start you off...

```
x = Sqrt[2^2 + 2^2]/2;
Show[
 ParametricPlot[{
   {x Cos[t], x Sin[t] + 2},
   {x Cos[t] + 2, x Sin[t]},
   {x Cos[t], x Sin[t] - 2},
   {x Cos[t] - 2, x Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
 Graphics[Line[{{2, 0}, {0, 2}}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: How did you come with with x=1.4?

Comment: @MuhminA The radius of the circles is `Sqrt[2^2 + 2^2]/2 = Sqrt[2] = 1.41421`

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe I can figure out the rest on my own from here.